# VB cable - how to change input sr, output sr?

Tags: audio, recording, audio-recording

This is a question about the software VB-cable. This program helps to record sound in PC.

MyPC (=a configuration in my PC) :

MyPC's internal sr/input sr/output sr : 48000Hz/48000Hz/44100Hz

[image]

#############################################################

manual (=a photo from VB-cable .pdf manual) :

manual's internal sr/input sr/output sr : 44100Hz/44100Hz/44100Hz

[image]

#############################################################

Umm I can change 'internal sr' easily. There is an option in the program.

[image]

So 'internal sr' is not a problem.

#############################################################

But I do not know how to change input sr, or output sr.

So in my PC, I have never seen other values than 48000Hz/44100Hz

for input sr/output sr.

Are these values completely determined by Hardware ?

If not, how can I change them ?

What about bits ? They are 24bit in MyPC, but 16bit in the photo of the manual.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the input will change the output and that they are linked too, otherwise the sound would have to be resampled, which forms a delay. The sample rate and bit rate are both tied to your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Taken together (LPChip, and answer from other site), input sr/output sr are tied to hardware. But one can control internal sr.